# How to add a CellDoubleClick handler to a grid Automatically generated

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am creating multiple pages to tab control

```
        foreach (Menus Menu in AllMenus)
        {
            TabPage ToAdd = new TabPage();
            _ProductsTabs.Controls.Add(ToAdd);
            ToAdd.Text = Menu.Menu;
            ToAdd.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(39,39,39);
        }
```

for each Tab i create next i add a grid and fill it with data from a SQL table

```
            #region AddGrids
        foreach (TabPage _Tab in _ProductsTabs.TabPages)
        {
            DataGridView ToAdd = new DataGridView();
            ToAdd.Size = new Size(1390, 584);
            ToAdd.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            ToAdd.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(39, 39, 39);
            ToAdd.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(41, 41, 41);
            ToAdd.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(49,49,49);
            ToAdd.GridColor = Color.FromArgb(49, 49, 49);
            ToAdd.ForeColor = Color.White;
            ToAdd.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            ToAdd.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            ToAdd.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            ToAdd.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn _Menu = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            _Menu.HeaderText = "Menu";
            _Menu.Name = "_MenuCol";
            _Menu.ReadOnly = true;
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn _Name = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            _Name.HeaderText = "Name";
            _Name.Name = "_NameCol";
            _Name.ReadOnly = true;
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn _Desc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            _Desc.HeaderText = "Description";
            _Desc.Name = "_DescCol";
            _Desc.Width = 250;
            _Desc.ReadOnly = true;
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn _Money = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            _Money.HeaderText = "Money";
            _Money.Name = "_MoneyCol";
            _Money.ReadOnly = true;
            _Tab.Controls.Add(ToAdd);
            ToAdd.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] { _Menu, _Name, _Desc , _Money });
            #region SqlGetEverthing

            #region SqlGetAllSubMenus

            string CurrSubMenu2 = "FindID";
            string Menu = "FindMenu";
            IEnumerable<SubMenus> results2;
            IEnumerable<Menus> CurMenu;
            Menus CurrMenu = new Menus();
            using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("data source=VBSS012;initial catalog=WinTest_Beta;integrated security=True"))
            {
                Con.Open();
                CurMenu = Con.Query<Menus>(Menu, new { Menu = _Tab.Text }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                Con.Close();
            }
            foreach (Menus _menu in CurMenu)
            {
                CurrMenu = _menu;
            }
            using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("data source=VBSS012;initial catalog=WinTest_Beta;integrated security=True"))
            {
                Con.Open();
                results2 = Con.Query<SubMenus>(CurrSubMenu2, new { SubMenu = CurrMenu.id }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                CurrSubMenu = results2;
                Con.Close();
            }

            #endregion

            #region FillGrid

            foreach (SubMenus _SubMenu in CurrSubMenu)
            {
                if (CurrMenu.id == _SubMenu.MenuID)
                {
                    ToAdd.Rows.Add(_SubMenu.Menu, _SubMenu.Name, _SubMenu.Descripton, _SubMenu.Price);
                }
            }

            ToAdd.Rows.Add("New", "New", "New", "New");

            #endregion

            #endregion
        }
```

Now i need to create a CellDoubleClick Handler for every grid that is created.
How i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like any other event handler:

```
ToAdd.CellDoubleClick += ToAdd_CellDoubleClick;
```